# Proper significant digits in terms of a characteristic scale

Tags: error-analysis

Suppose I have a defined quantity in a paper
$$g = 20\ \mathrm{meV}$$
and I wish to express the following equivalence (where $k_{B}$ is the Boltzmann constant which easily has more than 3-digit significance). Which of the following expresses proper significance?

$$\begin{align}
k_{B} \times 4.22\ \mathrm{K} &= 0.363\ \mathrm{meV} = 0.02g \tag{1}\\
k_{B} \times 4.22\ \mathrm{K} &= 0.363\ \mathrm{meV} = 0.018g \tag{2}\\
k_{B} \times 4.22\ \mathrm{K} &= 0.363\ \mathrm{meV} = 0.0182g \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

The first (left) equality in each of the above should be correct, yes?

**However, what about the latter (right) equivalences?**

On the one hand, the prefactor is obtained by computing the division of $0.363$ by $20$ (a number with only 1 significant digit) which would yield simply $0.02$. However, the process isn't reversible, if I multiply $0.2 \times 20$ I get $0.4$, not $0.363$.

Moreover, even with more significance given to the prefactor, the product on the right hand side is limited by the significance of $g$, which would seem to be $1$.

**Finally, since $g$ is a defined quantity, should we argue it has infinite significance, thereby making equation (3) above completely correct in both directions?**

Comment: Where did the 20meV and the 0.363meV come from? A measurement? In that case you need to give proper statistical and systematic errors for it. Denoting the accuracy of a measured quantity by significant figures is unacceptable.

Comment: g was inspired by an experimental measurement which has a proper value as you describe, 20.0 +- 0.05 meV or something, however, g is really a theoretical parameter that I insert into a simulation. Since I take g=20, exactly, then it has no uncertainty and (3) above should be correct, I think.

Answer (score 1):

If $g$ is a defined quantity it is essentially a unit conversion.  It may or may not have an uncertainty associated with it.  For example, the conversions $1m = 1000$ mm and $1$ inch = $2.54$ cm are exact.  The conversion $1$ kg $=2.20462$ pounds is not exact, but it is more accurate than anything else in your problem, so you can ignore the uncertainty.  So $(3)$ would be correct.  The really proper thing would be to show the error bounds with a $\pm$ sign, but if you don't have them in your original data, significant figures is about the best you can do.